# How to split a string into a list and get third element?

Tags: ruby

I use chef but I am a python developer.  I need to split a string that looks like this:

```
ms = "a-b-c-d"
```

I then need to get the third element which is 'c'

In python I would do this:

```
ms.split('-')[2]
```

What is the ruby way of doing it?

Comment: Will it always be a "c"? Or will it always be the third segment split by hyphens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the same:

```
ms.split('-')[2]
```